# How to deploy using Azure build agent to internal server?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops

I am using ( **Agent pool : Azure pipeline ; Agent specification : windows-2019** )
for CI/CD build, I also want same agent to deploy war to Azure VM which is bound to specific domain.

Although, **I am able to deploy war using self hosted agent**, but for this I have to allocate one VM for CI/CD builds. 
I want to eliminate this and use the same agent to build and deploy war to server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Microsoft-provided hosted agents don't have connectivity to your on-prem environment. If you need to deploy to a server that is not internet-addressable, then you need to create a private agent within your network.

Comment: well, not necessary, you can probably use ssh tunneling :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#communication-to-deploy-to-target-servers):

*If your on-premises environments do not have connectivity to a Microsoft-hosted agent pool (which is typically the case due to intermediate firewalls), you'll need to manually configure a self-hosted agent on on-premises computer(s).*

If in your case, it's the internal firewalls that block the hosted agent, I think you do have the need to use self-agent for deployment. Otherwise, you can try port forwarding like `4c74356b41` suggests.